# Secondary index on cassandra column family returns 0 rows

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

To start with i am new to Cassandra or rather nosql. I have a column family with couple of primary keys and some columns i would like to query on.

```
create table destination (
destid int,
destDesc text,
phone text,
destphone text,
primary key(destid));

create index on destination(destphone));
```

so when i query

`selecy * from destination where destphone='1234567899';` it returns 0 rows.

One more thing i would like to bring here is i have created a index after i have inserted all the data in the table. is it ok?

Comment: Yes it is ok to create secondary index later. Returning 0 rows means that you don't have value 1234567899 for destphone. Also if you have more than one nodes try query with consistency ALL

Comment: @Undefined_variable that is the problem, the value with which i am searching is present in the table. So i am not sure why it returns 0 rows. i will try with the CONSISTENCY ALL though.